# Best way to structure local python packages without pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded-linux

Ok, I am sure this is a very stupid question, which should already be answered many times. But I cannot find any good solution, which works for me.

**My Problem:** I have a package, let's call it `my_pack`. This contains the following files:

- `__init__.py`:

```
import A
```

- `A.py`:

```
import B
def A():
   B.B()
if __name__=='__main__':
   A()
```

- `B.py`:

```
def B():
   print('B Called')
```

And I want to:

- Use the package `my_pack` as standalone application, e.g. call `python3 A.py`
- Import it from other python scripts, which are located in different locations.
- *Don't* use pip: The application will be deployed on an embedded system, where pip is not installed by default. Preferably, I do not want to have to include pip just for that.

**Current approaches:**

- Use absolute paths everywhere. This is obviously really ugly, and I do not want to do this.
- Create a local (pip) package. As far as I know, the only easy way to do this is using pip. Which is not ideal for my case.
- Use relative imports and edit the python path in each `__init__.py` file. This works, but is also quite ugly.
- Add the package to the python-path: In theory this should work, but I'm having quite a few troubles with the relative imports inside the package. Which leads me to think, that this is also not a good solution. The problems are:

  - Inside the package, I would rather not use relative imports. Just because I then need to convert all normal imports to relative imports.
  - Currently, I am getting a `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` Error. I am sure, this can be solved, but I am not sure how easy or nice a solution to this is.

Currently, my preferred solution is to add it to the python path and use relative imports. However, I don't think, that my current approach to this is nice. I think, that Python should have a better, simpler solution.

Am I missing some other possibility? Or is this just a problem, where python does not have a nice solution to?

I am using python3.9.5

Answer (score 0):

now your workdir is "/home/name/hh"
but you want to import from this directory "/home/name/kk/" 
/home/name/kk/A.py
/home/name/kk/C.py
/home/name/kk/K.py
/home/name/kk/**init**.py
you can use "sys" to add a python environment path

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"/home/name/kk")
import K
import A
import C
```